# Question concerning SCJP-6 exam

Tags: java, generics, scjp

While preparing for the SCJP-6 exam I faced with a difficult issue. I can’t find answer by myself. Please, answer for the question and give short comments:

```
abstract class A<K extends Number> {
   // insert code here
}
```

1. `public abstract <K> A<? extends Number> useMe(A<? super K> k);`
2. `public abstract <K> A<? super Number> useMe(A<? extends K> k);`
3. `public abstract <K> A<K> useMe(A<K> k);`
4. `public abstract <V extends K> A<V> useMe(A<V> k);`
5. `public abstract <V super K> A<V> useMe(A<V> k);`
6. `public abstract <V extends Character> A<? super V> useMe(A<K> k);`
7. `public abstract <V super Character> A<? super V> useMe(A<K> k);`

Which method can be inserted in the placeholder above?

P.S.
I tried to look on the specification. Those one was not helpful for me.

Comment: That's a tough one. I'm curious to know the answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Please fix the abstract class declaration (the part after the 'extends' keyword)

Comment: @Eyal Schneider: Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 1,2,3: The generic type `K` shadowed class type `K`. In those methods `K` is just new generic type. Compiler tries to pass conditional evaluation `<K extends Number>`. Method 1,2 passes and 3 - fails.

Answer 4 is completely correct.

Answer 5,7 has syntax error.

Answer 6 incorrect, because test `<V extends Number>` will fail.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to go about this is to try each one and see what the compiler tells you.  I get the following results for each one (using NetBeans, so your results may vary slightly):

```
public abstract <K> A<? extends Number> useMe(A<? super K> k);
// seems to work

public abstract <K> A<? super Number> useMe(A<? extends K> k);
// type parameter ? extends K is not within its bound

public abstract <K> A<K> useMe(A<K> k);
// type parameter K is not within its bound

public abstract <V extends K> A<V> useMe(A<V> k);
// seems to work

public abstract <V super K> A<V> useMe(A<V> k);
// > expected
// illegal start of type
// <identifier> expected
// missing method body, or declare abstract
// cannot find symbol
//   symbol: class V
//   location: class A<K>

public abstract <V extends Character> A<? super V> useMe(A<K> k);
// type parameter ? super V is not within its bound

public abstract <V super Character> A<? super V> useMe(A<K> k);
// > expected
// illegal start of type
// <identifier> expected
// missing method body, or declare abstract
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also tried to feed the compiler with this code. I want to understand compiler's logic. For example, third variant: why "K" is not within bounds?

Comment: @abatishchev: The class declaration specifies that `K extends Number`, but the third variant uses an unbounded `K`.  I'd Google each error message, or check out the Java [Generics Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for more details on what's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain a bit more...

1 does not work because you cannot substitute `A<? super K>` for `A<K extends Number>`... no guarantee that a superclass extends the same class as the subclass.

1, 2 and 3 do not work because the initial type parameter  hides the original K used in the class declaration.

5 does not work because `<V super K>` cannot substitute for `<K extends Number>`... no guarantee that a superclass extends the same class as the subclass.

6 & 7 should be obvious.

4 works because if we know V extends K then we know V extends Number (since all classes that K extends V extends). We can therefore substitute `A<V>` for `<K extends Number>`.

I hope this makes sense... someone may be able to come along and explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Only the second (`public abstract  A useMe(A k);`) seems to work, just plugging it into an IDE.